# Llamar dinámicamente a métodos, dentro de una clase, con Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, clase, método

Mejor un ejemplo funcional, fuera de una clase, para saber a qué me refiero:

```
def saludar():
   print('Hola')

func = 'saludar'
func()
```

Pero si trato de hacer lo mismo pero dentro de una clase, no me funciona ya que me dice que no se encuentra ningún método de clase con el nombre "func".

Entiendo que el problema desde el punto de vista de Python, ya que está buscando una función con el nombre "func", lo que no sé es cómo indicarle (si se puede) que ese "c.func()" es realmente "c.saludar()".

```
class Persona:

   def saludar(self):
      print('Hola')

func = 'saludar'

c = Persona()
c.func()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar `getattr`.

Modifique un poco tu código para mostrar que también puedes pasar paramétros (en este caso, el nombre de la persona) y recibir resultados (el nombre en mayúsculas:

```
class Persona:

   def saludar(self, nombre):
       print('Hola', nombre)
       return nombre.upper()

func = 'saludar'

c = Persona()
nuevo = getattr(c, func)("Juan")
print(nuevo)
```

produce:

```
Hola Juan
JUAN
```

**El método getattr**

> [getattr(object, name[, default])](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr)
>
> Return the value of the named attribute of object. name must be a
> string. If the string is the name of one of the object’s attributes,
> the result is the value of that attribute. For example, getattr(x,
> 'foobar') is equivalent to x.foobar. If the named attribute does not
> exist, default is returned if provided, otherwise AttributeError is
> raised.

Retorna el valor del atributo nombrado. El nombre debe ser un string. Si el nombre corresponde a un método, el método es ejecutado y su valor devuelto. Si el atributo no existe, se retorna el valor por default si se especifico uno. En caso contrario, levanta un AttributeError

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda aunque no encuentro la lógica de que si no hay un parámetro no hace nada. Si obvio el parámetro "nombre", no hace nada, tampoco dá error, pero si pongo el parámetro, entonces ejecuta el print.

Comment: @CarlosDiaz. Si sacas el parámetro, entonces no calza la definición de la función con la llamada, lo que es un error. Lo puse ahí solo para demostración. Si lo omites en la definición y en la invocación, todo funcionara OK. Puedes ajustar el ejemplo a tus necesidades.

Comment: gracas de nuevo por la solución